# nhibernate insert question - have id but not entity object

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm

Using NHibernate I need to insert an entity into a database that has a child entity. Example:

```
public class Reservation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Service Service { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I need to create a new Reservation and insert it. However, when constructing the Reservation for insertion, I don't have the Service entity, but I do have the Service's Id value. Is there a way to insert my reservation without fetching the Service first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use NHibernate's Load method.  This will create a proxy for the Service object, but it will not actually hit the database.  See this [blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/30/nhibernate-ndash-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by.aspx) for the difference between load and get.

Comment: Dude. This is gonna help us so much! We have ReportingQuery to select without Entity. Now we can Update. NICE!